# Insert array in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

how to insert inner array in mongodb using php I run this command in sheel then it runs

`db.domain_data.update({"email":"rohan@walkover.in","url.tlds":".com"},{'$addToSet':{"url.$.domain":{"name":"rohan","status":"yes"}}}})`

but I write this code in php then it not works

```
<?
    $domain=array("name"=>"asvdsfs","status"=>"yes");
    $condition=array("email"=>"rohan@walkover.in","url"=>array("tlds"=>".com"));
    $arr=array('$addToSet'=>array("url.$.domain"=>array($domain)));
    //$arr=array('$addToSet'=>array("url"=>array("$"=>array("domain"=>array($domain)))));
    //Above line also not working.
    $status=$db->domain_data->update($condition,array($arr));
?>
```

How to write above php code that it will run correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably have extra array

```
<?     
      $domain=array("name"=>"asvdsfs","status"=>"yes");     
      $condition=array("email"=>"rohan@walkover.in","url.tlds"=>".com");//1 more change//,"url"=>array("tlds"=>".com")          
      $arr=array('$addToSet'=>array("url.$.domain"=>$domain));    // change this line 
      //$arr=array('$addToSet'=>array("url"=>array("$"=>array("domain"=>array($domain)))));     
      //Above line also not working.     
      $status=$db->domain_data->update($condition,$arr);   // change this line 

?>
```